# SQL - using tables to find out How many types of each book a publisher has

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables, publishers and titles.

I want to find out how many types of each book the publisher has, such as history, childrens, etc.

Here are the two tables:

```
CREATE TABLE publishers
  (
  pub_id   CHAR(3)     NOT NULL,
  pub_name VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
  city     VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
  state    CHAR(2)             ,
  country  VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT pk_publishers PRIMARY KEY (pub_id)
  )ENGINE = InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE titles
  (
  title_id   CHAR(3)      NOT NULL,
  title_name VARCHAR(40)  NOT NULL,
  type       VARCHAR(10)          ,
  pub_id     CHAR(3)      NOT NULL,
  pages      INTEGER              ,
  price      DECIMAL(5,2)         ,
  sales      INTEGER              ,
  pubdate    DATE                 ,
  contract   SMALLINT     NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT pk_titles PRIMARY KEY (title_id)
  )ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

All I have been able to do so far is find out the total count of types(genres) of books.

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT type)
FROM publishers AS a
INNER JOIN titles AS p
ON a.pub_id = p.pub_id;
```

How can I go about doing this?

Comment: You want to look up [`GROUP BY`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177673.aspx).  Use your query and group by `pub_id` and `type` and count those.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have a query with Group By as shown below

```
SELECT a.pub_id, a.pub_name, p.type,  COUNT(DISTINCT p.type)
FROM publishers AS a
INNER JOIN titles AS p ON a.pub_id = p.pub_id
GROUP BY a.pub_id, a.pub_name, p.type
```

add group by for pub_id and pub_name to avoid two publishers having same name to be considered as one publisher

Answer (score 0):

Try this out: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9331e/24

```
SELECT p.pub_name, t.type, count(t.type)
FROM publishers AS p
INNER JOIN titles AS t on t.pub_id = p.pub_id
GROUP BY p.pub_id, t.type
```